# Micropython SPI transfer with non-standard number of bits

Tags: esp32, spi, micropython

I'm using micropython on an ESP32.

I need to transfer exactly 10 bits of data via the SPI interface. Since I did not find a way using the standard SPI methods provided, I ended up with my own implementation which unfortunately is incredidbly slow compared to the standard hardware supported methods.

Obviously, there has been some discussion going on here but I can't find out how it was finally implemented:
https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/5225

The standard SPI constructor is this:

```
SPI.init(baudrate=1000000, *, polarity=0, phase=0, bits=8, firstbit=SPI.MSB, sck=None, mosi=None, miso=None, pins=(SCK, MOSI, MISO))
```

Some devices just work the "don't care for the other bits" way, but mine does not.

What I can't do is send a sequence of two bytes like **[XXXXXXBB][BBBBBBBB]**, where X are the "don't mind" bits and B are the bits that represent the needed data. Also the other way like **[BBBBBBBB][BBXXXXXX]** is not an option, I need to send/clock exactly 10 bits.

Any idea how to do this with the SPI.init() parameters? How would I have to set up the bytearray to store this data?

Answer (score -1):

try set `bits=8 no bits=10`

```
SPI.init(baudrate=1000000, *, polarity=0, phase=0, bits=10, firstbit=SPI.MSB, sck=None, mosi=None, miso=None, pins=(SCK, MOSI, MISO))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).